# Permission denied when creating a folder

Tags: file-io, file-permissions, php

I am creating a directory in php it is working nicely in localhost but when I run in my server am getting error as

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in D:\Hosting\8089251\html\songs\test.php on line 12

How to give permission to server?  I saw the php info in my server the virtual directory support is disabled? Is beacuse of that I am not able to create a directory? if so tell me how to enable virtual director support

Answer (score 0):

> How to give permission to server? I saw the php info in my server the virtual directory support is disabled? Is beacuse of that I am not able to create a directory? if so tell me how to enable virtual director support

It's not. The reason you can't create the directory is a very simple one: you don't have the permission to do so as stated in the error message. Generally, this means that the user PHP is running under isn't the same as the that owns the directory you're trying to create the directory in.

If your server is under your control, please read up on how permissions work under Windows (I imagine you'll have to add a group that has control over the directory). This stuff is important, so if you do have your own server, be sure to read and understand how permissions work, or your server will be ruined in the quickest of times.

If your server is actually maintained by someone else, give them a call. If all permissions are correct, mkdir should be able to create a new directory, so apparently the permissions aren't correct. If the server is not under your control, there's nothing to do about it other than telling the one who maintains the server to get his permissions straight.